# SSH to a server and exit Python script (in the same shell)

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I'm running a script that's determining login information for me, and in the end is outputting the login information that I need to use.

I am running the script in a terminal, and now I want it to SSH me with the credentials it has, exit the Python script on my computer and connect my current terminal to the new server.

Say I already have my sshHost, sshUser and sshPass as variables in the script. How do I run an SSH command in the current terminal and connect to that server?

I tried subprocess and spur, however I didn't really manage to get that going.

I would really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: I've written a simple tool which did exactly what you want, you can take a look at it. [sshhelper](https://github.com/piglei/sshhelper/blob/master/sshhelper#L163-L201)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the python prints the settings to stdout;

```
#!/bin/sh
export $(credentials.py)
exec ssh hostname
```